# How to use dependency injection with routes in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection, routes

How to configure route instances (`Illuminate/Support/Facades/Route.php`) to use already registered services through DI?

For example I register my singleton:

```
$this->app->singleton('api_controller', function ($app) {
    return new Controller('config_value');
});
```

And controller itself:

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
   private $configValue;

   public function __construct(string $configValue)
   {
      $this->configValue = $configValue;
   }

   public function getConfigValue()
   {
       return $this->configValue;
   }
}
```

Then declaring route:

```
Route::get('config-value', 'ApiController@getConfigValue')->name('getConfigValue');
```

But after calling the API, Route initiates new instance of ApiController, and not the one I declared as singleton so config_value is not passed to controller. Is it possible to configure Route instances?

Tried alternate route with app instance, but it does not seem to find api_controller service:

```
Route::get('config-value', function () { return app('api_controller')->getConfigValue(); })->name('getConfigValue');

In Container.php line 752:

  Class api_controller does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only way to achieve this is by using auto wire (and not by custom service id declaration, which kind of stricts you out of multiple instances configuration). Also it needs explicitly `defer false` to be able to override new instances.

```
protected $defer = false;
$this->app->singleton(Controller::class, function ($app) {
    return new Controller('config_value');
});
```